# Google Spreadsheet script to merge cells in column A containing 'Hello' with the adjacent cell in column B

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to merge cells containing a certain word in column A  (e.g. 'Hello') with the cell to the immediate right (in column B)

E.g. `A4 = 'Hello'`, therefore I would like to merge cells A4 and B4.

I have this code so far:

```
function formatCells() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Combined');
  var range = s.getDataRange()
  var values = range.getValues();

  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
    if (values[row][1] == 'Hello')
      {s.getRange(row+1,1).mergeAcross();
}
}
```

But the code doesn't seem to be doing anything at all? Can anyone out there kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks for looking.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Arrays are 0 indexed,so column A is index 0...
You should simply use `values[row][0]`  in your condition.

And to mergeAcross two cells you'll need to get a 2 cells range like this :

```
s.getRange(row+1,1,1,2).mergeAcross();
```

Note also that you will loose the value that was in column B since the merge method doesn't merge contents. I don't know if thar's an issue for you...

Comment: I realise what I was doing wrong now, thanks to your kind help! Thanks again.