# Merge Number of Cells based on Another Cell Value - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to merge some cells (horizontally)  starting on C13 and the number of cells I need to merge is the value found on B4; therefore, if B4 = 5, I want to merge cells C13:G13.  Of course the cell in B4 will be dynamic. This will be on Sheet1.

It should be an easy one, but for the life of me I can get the programming correct.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? You have tagged this question as a GAS question, so... can you: Access the value in a cell? Create a range? Use that range's [`mergeAcross()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#mergeacross) function? Show us what you have tried, if the `mergeAcross` hint is not sufficient.

Comment: Otherwise, welcome to Stack Overflow. You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance. But try to help us to help you by showing us what your _specific_ problem is (with code, ideally). And you can show what [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494731/google-spreadsheet-script-to-merge-cells-in-column-a-containing-hello-with-the) you have done, also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.